# formato de fecha y hora moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Estoy obteniendo el siguiente formato de fecha desde una Query:

```
Oct  6 2021 11:43:34:000AM
```

y quiero formatearlo al siguiente formato, uno para la fecha y otro la hora con moment.js:

```
Fecha: 06-10-2021
Hora 11:43
```

Comment: Muestra lo que has intentado hasta el momento: lee [ask].

Answer (score -1):

Estimados gracias a los que leyeron o intentaron ayudarme, encontré la solución y se las dejare por si a alguien le sirve:

**Fecha :** moment(item.Fecha,['DDMMMMY', 'MMMMDDY']).format('MM-DD-YYYY');

**Hora:**  moment(item.Fecha,['DDMMMMY HH:mm:ss', 'MMMMDDY HH:mm:ss']).add(24, 'hours').format('HH:mm');

Comment: Recordá que la respuesta es de utilidad no solo para vos, sino para los demás miembros de la comunidad. Por lo tanto, debés explicar brevemente tu respuesta, _evitando así fomentar el copypaste_: leé [answer]. No olvides además [aceptar tu respuesta](/help/accepted-answer) cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.

Comment: Para fecha de entrada en el formato que muestras con PM no funciona, pone 11:43 en vez de 23:43.